# How to run the AWS codepipeline with Github release tag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to run the AWS codepipeline when there is a new tag in the ECR repo. I am using GitHub action with release tag and pushing the Docker image to ECR. Now the issue is, I want to give the release tags to images like 1.0, 1.1 but at the source stage of codepipeline we need to specify the image tag otherwise it takes `latest` as default [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSGGx.png) due to this codepipeline is not triggering because it is not getting the latest tag.

I want to give the release number as an image tag. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can't. A pipeline can only use a single and specific tag in an ECR source.

You would have to hack around it by modifying the pipeline on each deploy as part of your CI/CD process.

Comment: Like this one? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/deploying-to-amazon-elastic-container-service

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score -2):

I found a way to achieve this with GitHub Action. The thing is when the pipeline will trigger the task definition gets updated every time.

We can follow this documentation. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/deploying-to-amazon-elastic-container-service

Comment: The question was about CodePipeline, though.